# Regex that splits long text in separate sentences with match()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, pattern-matching, match

This is a textarea where the user writes some text. I've written an example in it.

```
<textarea id="text">First sentence. Second sentence? Third sentence!
Fourth sentence.

Fifth sentence
</textarea>
```

**Requirements already considered in the regex**

- separator is included in array item
- last sentence doesn't necessarily require a separator character (it can end with any character)
- if a sentence has more than one separator char, it is included in the array item. Example: **second sentence?!?** should be [...,"second sentence?!?",...]

**Missing requirement (I need help with this) <<**

Each new line should be represented by an empty array item. If the regex is applied, this should be the response:

```
["First sentence.", "Second sentence?", "Third sentence!", "", "Fourth sentence.", "", "", "Fifth sentence"]
```

Instead, I'm receiving this:

```
["First sentence.", "Second sentence?", "Third sentence!", "Fourth sentence.", "Fifth sentence"]
```

This is the regex and match call:

```
var tregex = /[^\r\n.!?]+(:?(:?\r\n|[\r\n]|[.!?])+|$)/gi;
var sentences = $('#text').val().match(tregex).map($.trim);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified it a lot, either match the end of a line (new line) or a sentence followed by punctuation:

```
var tregex = /\n|([^\r\n.!?]+([.!?]+|$))/gim;
```

I also believe the `m` flag for multiline is important

Comment: hi, thanks! im testing it with several scenarios, but it is always returning an unnecessary empty array item at the last position of the array. For some reason, it takes \t (tabs) as new lines as well.

Comment: changing `$` to `\n` should fix it. I'm really not sure why I opted to use `$` in the first place

Comment: hi, i just noticed that your regex doesn't cover the third requirement (it was previously covered in my regex). Any ideas?

Comment: I fixed it, just add a plus after the `[.!?]`

Comment: arghhh sorry, i was testing other approaches and didn't get the response i wanted. that last tip worked fine :)

Comment: If the line has email addresses in it, it ends the line in the middle of it... not trying to bash what you posted, I made it work. But -- is there a way to account for that?

Comment: It thinks that space is a separate sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/((?:\S[^\.\?\!]*)[\.\?\!]*)/g
```

Lets break this down:

"**g**" is for flag for global match, meaning keep matching after the first occurrence

Working from the inside out, **(?:)** is a delimiter that allows us to group an expression, but discard the matched result from the output. We are matching **\S** (non-whitespace) that does not contain a period, question mark, or exclamation point.

You stated you wanted to keep this punctuation, so the next part following the match **[.\?!]** is a series which contains these same punctuation symbols so they are included in the outer delimiters. EDIT: I added the asterisk for this to include any number of punctuation, or none at all at the end of a sentence.

Check out the matched groups using http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm, or a similar Javascript regex tester.

Comment: hi, actually that regex doesn't convert the \n to empty array items and now the third listed requirement doesn't work at all :s

Comment: I added the asterisk for this to include any number of punctuation, or none at all at the end of a sentence.