# XPages - format data in a computed field

Tags: xpages

In my XPage, I have a computed field which displays several lines of text. I would like to display the field contents so that each sentence displays on a new line i.e. format the output so that a newline character is added to each sentence. How can I do this?

Comment: Tony are you already using any existing javascript libraries?

Comment: I use Dojo for some tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set property `escape` to "false" in computed field then you can get newlines with `<br />`. Assuming, you mean as a sentence a string ending with a period then you can use `replace()` to put the `<br />` into your text:

```
<xp:text
    escape="false"
    id="computedField1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        yourValue.replace(". ", ".<br />")}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

This is of course a very simple version. You'd get a newline if somewhere in the middle of a sentence is a period and you wouldn't get a newline if sentence ends with an exclamation or question mark. You should use a more sophisticated regular expression as parameters for replace() like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166217/2065611).

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I got this working using:                   var fieldval = document1.getValue("S1B3_Text1");
@ReplaceSubstring(fieldval,@NewLine(), "<br />")

Comment: Oh, you had newlines in your text already - then it's easier - lucky you :)

Comment: Yes, the new lines were present in Notes but not displaying on the web. That was the required change. Thanks again for your tip.

Comment: There is an even easier solution for your case if you use inputTextarea instead of computed text: `<xp:inputTextarea
  id="inputTextarea1"
  readonly="true"
  value="#{document1.S1B3_Text1}" />`